# How to generate Ajax Paging Navigation in Wicket with ListView?

Tags: ajax, listview, wicket, java-ee-6, dropdownchoice

I have a HTML markup for Ajax Paging Navigation like:

```
<div class="btn-group">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
                    <i class="ico ico-prev"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown2 inline">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-shorter">
                        <strong>1-8</strong>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu spec_width">
                            <li><a data-ico="1" href="#">10-30</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">30-40</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">40-50</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">50-60</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
                    <i class="ico ico-next"></i>
                </a>
```

when user choose interval of pages (10-30, 30-40 etc) the data is changing (Ajax). 
How I can implement it with ListView in wicket? I think that it should be smth like:

```
ListView yourListView = new ListView("your-list-view", new PropertyModel(this, "pages")){
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            item.add(new Label("label", item.toString()));
        }
    };
```

and markup:

```
<ul><li wicket:id="your-list-view"><span wicket:id="label"></span></li></ul>
```

I exactly know, how to do it with DropDownChoice, but it isn't suitable in my case, because I have to generate `<ul><li></li></ul>` instead of `<select><option></option></select>` tags.
p/s: sample how to do it with **DropDownChoice**:

```
public abstract class AjaxPagingPanel extends Panel{
private Criteria criteria;
private List<Page> pages; 
private Page currentPage;    
private long listSize;
private int pagesCount;
private DropDownChoice pagingDropDownChoice;
private Label pagingSizeLabel;
private AjaxLink previousLink;
private AjaxLink nextLink;

public AjaxPagingPanel(String id, Criteria pagingCriteria) {
    super(id);

    criteria = pagingCriteria;
    listSize = criteria.getResultSize();
    pagesCount = (int) Math.ceil((double) listSize / criteria.getPageSize());

    long pageSize = pagingCriteria.getPageSize();
    currentPage = new Page(pagingCriteria.getPageNum(), (pagingCriteria.getPageNum() -        1) * pageSize + 1, Math.min( pagingCriteria.getPageNum() * pageSize,  pagingCriteria.getResultSize()) ); // Model for DropDownChoice

    pages = new ArrayList(pagesCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < pagesCount; i++) {
         pages.add(new Page(i + 1, i * pageSize + 1, Math.min((i + 1) * pageSize,   pagingCriteria.getResultSize()) ));            
    }

    // Label updated by ajax to render listSize
    pagingSizeLabel = new Label("pageSize", new PropertyModel(this, "listSize"));
    add(pagingSizeLabel.setOutputMarkupId(true));

    // Ajax DropDownChoice used as Page navigator
    pagingDropDownChoice = new DropDownChoice("pagesDropDown", new PropertyModel(this,  "currentPage"), new PropertyModel(this, "pages"), new ChoiceRenderer("period", "pageNum"));
    pagingDropDownChoice.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

            criteria.setPageNum((int)currentPage.getPageNum());
            updatePagingList(target);
            setLinkVisibility();                
            target.add(pagingSizeLabel);
            target.add(pagingDropDownChoice);
            target.add(nextLink);
            target.add(previousLink);
        }
    });
    add(pagingDropDownChoice.setOutputMarkupId(true));

    add(previousLink = new IndicatingAjaxLink("previousLink"){

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            if (criteria.getPageNum() > 1) {                    
                criteria.setPageNum(criteria.getPageNum() - 1);
                int index = pages.indexOf(currentPage);
                currentPage = pages.get(index - 1);       
                updatePagingList(target);
                setLinkVisibility();
                target.add(pagingSizeLabel);
                target.add(pagingDropDownChoice);
                target.add(nextLink);
                target.add(previousLink);
            }
        }
    });
    previousLink.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);

    // Next link of Page navigator
    add(nextLink = new IndicatingAjaxLink("nextLink"){

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            if (criteria.getPageNum() < pagesCount) { 

                criteria.setPageNum(criteria.getPageNum() + 1);     
                int index = pages.indexOf(currentPage);
                currentPage = pages.get(index + 1);
                updatePagingList(target);
                setLinkVisibility();
                target.add(pagingSizeLabel);
                target.add(pagingDropDownChoice);
                target.add(nextLink);
                target.add(previousLink);
            }
        }
    });
    nextLink.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);

    setLinkVisibility();
}

public Page getCurrentPage() {
    return currentPage;
}

public void setCurrentPage(Page currentPage) {
    this.currentPage = currentPage;
}

public final void setLinkVisibility() {
    if (criteria.getPageNum() == 1) {
        previousLink.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        previousLink.setVisible(true);
    }

    if (criteria.getPageNum() == pagesCount || pagesCount == 0) {
        nextLink.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        nextLink.setVisible(true);
    }
}

// Method must be overrided by a class which is using AjaxPagingPanel
public abstract void updatePagingList(AjaxRequestTarget target);

// Method to refresh the AjaxPagingPanel, for example after Ajax search
public void refresh(Criteria pagingCriteria, AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    criteria = pagingCriteria;
    listSize = criteria.getResultSize();
    pagesCount = (int) Math.ceil((double) listSize / criteria.getPageSize());

    long pageSize = pagingCriteria.getPageSize();
    currentPage = new Page(pagingCriteria.getPageNum(), (pagingCriteria.getPageNum() - 1) * pageSize + 1, Math.min( pagingCriteria.getPageNum() * pageSize,   pagingCriteria.getResultSize()) ); 

    pages.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < pagesCount; i++) {
        pages.add(new Page(i + 1, i * pageSize + 1, Math.min((i + 1) * pageSize,  pagingCriteria.getResultSize()) ));            
    }

    pagingDropDownChoice.modelChanged();
    setLinkVisibility();
    target.add(pagingSizeLabel);
    target.add(pagingDropDownChoice);
    target.add(nextLink);
    target.add(previousLink);
}

/**
 * This class is used as a model class in DropDownChoice component and
 * provides list of page as [1-50] [51-100] [101-150] [151-200]...
 */
 public class Page implements Serializable{
    private long pageNum;
    private long firstPage;
    private long lastPage;

    public Page(long pageNum, long firstPage, long lastPage) {
        this.pageNum = pageNum;
        this.firstPage = firstPage;
        this.lastPage = lastPage;
    }

    public long getPageNum() {
        return pageNum;
    }

    public void setPageNum(long pageNum) {
        this.pageNum = pageNum;
    }

    public String getPeriod() {
        return Long.toString(firstPage) + "-" + Long.toString(lastPage);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(!(obj instanceof Page)){
            return false;
        }
        return this.pageNum == ((Page)obj).pageNum;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 59 * hash + (int) (this.pageNum ^ (this.pageNum >>> 32));
        return hash;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a simple `ListView` and trying to build your own paging support, you likely want a [`PageableListView`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/list/PageableListView.html) and an attached [`AjaxPagingNavigator`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/markup/html/navigation/paging/AjaxPagingNavigator.html).

The `PageableListView` extends `ListView` to add support for paging and the `AjaxPagingNavigator` supplies the navigation UI for the paging.

There are other repeaters that can be made to support paging, but this is the closest to what you're currently doing.

If you're using hibernate to access your database, you might want to look at [`DataView`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/repeater/data/DataView.html) for good support of paging.